# GWT unresolved types

Tags: gwt, maven, compilation, pom.xml

**Situation:**

I've got two projects

- Project A.: A native maven project "core" (domain)
- Project B.: A GWT maven project "application" (GUI)
- I use Eclipse Helios and GWT 2.4

**Problem:**

I cann't use the B. in A. correct.

It is possible to use my own classes from B. in A. but my own classes importes classes from an other jar (org.javatuples).

When GWT is compiling the client code it throws an error message:

```
"[ERROR] <no source info>: public abstract class org.javatuples.Tuple
    extends java.lang.Object
    implements : Iterable<java.lang.Object>, java.io.Serializable, Comparable<org.javatuples.Tuple>
```

Here ist the full stack trace:

```
Compiling module org.dialoguemaps.dialoguemaps
   Validating newly compiled units
      Ignored 5 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Failed to get JNode
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:140)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.getType(BuildTypeMap.java:730)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.createField(BuildTypeMap.java:570)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.access$300(BuildTypeMap.java:99)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap$BuildDeclMapVisitor.visit(BuildTypeMap.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.FieldDeclaration.traverse(FieldDeclaration.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1232)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:687)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.createPeersForNonTypeDecls(BuildTypeMap.java:637)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.exec(BuildTypeMap.java:514)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.exec(BuildTypeMap.java:523)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:599)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:233)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
      [ERROR] <no source info>: public abstract class org.javatuples.Tuple
    extends java.lang.Object
    implements : Iterable<java.lang.Object>, java.io.Serializable, Comparable<org.javatuples.Tuple>
/*   fields   */
private static final [unresolved] long serialVersionUID
private final [unresolved] java.lang.Object[] valueArray
private final [unresolved] List<java.lang.Object> valueList
/*   methods   */
protected transient void <init>(java.lang.Object[]) 
protected transient void <init>(int, java.lang.Object[]) 
public int compareTo(org.javatuples.Tuple) 
[unresolved] public final boolean contains(java.lang.Object) 
[unresolved] public final boolean containsAll(Collection<?>) 
[unresolved] public final transient boolean containsAll(java.lang.Object[]) 
public final boolean equals(java.lang.Object) 
public abstract int getSize() 
[unresolved] public final java.lang.Object getValue(int) 
public final int hashCode() 
[unresolved] public final int indexOf(java.lang.Object) 
public final Iterator<java.lang.Object> iterator() 
[unresolved] public final int lastIndexOf(java.lang.Object) 
[unresolved] public final java.lang.Object[] toArray() 
[unresolved] public final List<java.lang.Object> toList() 
public final java.lang.String toString() 
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding
[ERROR] at MultiID.java(17): private final Tuple _value;
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.FieldDeclaration
```

And here are the pom.xml from A. and the pom.xml from B.:

*pom.xml A.:*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.dialoguemaps</groupId>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>core</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
      <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/home/arno/.workspace/dialoguemaps-core/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>/home/arno/.workspace/dialoguemaps-core/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/home/arno/.workspace/dialoguemaps-core/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/home/arno/.workspace/dialoguemaps-core/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/home/arno/.workspace/dialoguemaps-core/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>/home/arno/.workspace/dialoguemaps-core/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/home/arno/.workspace/dialoguemaps-core/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>/home/arno/.workspace/dialoguemaps-core/target</directory>
    <finalName>core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/arno/.workspace/dialoguemaps-core/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/arno/.workspace/dialoguemaps-core/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/home/arno/.workspace/dialoguemaps-core/target/site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>/home/arno/.workspace/dialoguemaps-core/target/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

*pom.xml B.:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.dialoguemaps</groupId>
    <artifactId>dialoguemaps</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GWT Maven Archetype</name>

    <properties>
        <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
        <gwtVersion>2.4.0</gwtVersion>
        <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vectomatic</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-gwt-svg</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
            <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
        <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

        <plugins>

            <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                            <goal>i18n</goal>
                            <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
                    documentation at codehaus.org -->
                <configuration>
                    <runTarget>dialoguemaps.html</runTarget>
                    <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>org.dialoguemaps.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exploded</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>smartclient</id>
            <name>smartclient.com</name>
            <url>http://www.smartclient.com/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

**Questions:**

- Is it a maven dependencie problem?
- Is it a GWT problem because GWT cannt compile the class types Tuple?
- Have you a solution or an idea how to solve this problem?

Regards
Arno

Answer (score 0):

Project A jar's must be delivered with source code if you wan't to use it into another GWT project.
Add this in its pom build section:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/client/**</include>
      <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>   
</resources>
```

adjust the "client" include pattern to your projects source path and rebuild. Once .java classes will be available for children project, it will compile.

Comment: Thank you,Arcadien. Sounds good but dont't work. Project A isn't an other GWT project. It is a native Maven project without \*\*/client/\*\* and \*\*/*.gwt.xml. The missing jar is a maven dependency (path: /home/arno/.m2/repository/org/javatuples/javatuples/1.2/javatuples-1.2-sources.jar)

Comment: ok! btw, to use java code inside your GWT project, GWT compiler need the xxx.gwt.xml file. You have to write one and put it into the javatuples-1.2-sources.j‌​ar. Even that file only contains a single path, it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use or reference javatuples in GWT client code, because that library uses java features that cannot be compiled to javascript code.

Comment: See http://javatuples-users.973651.n3.nabble.com/javatuples-users-GWT-support-td3881558.html